# How can I send a message to a parent window with a script from another domain?

Tags: javascript, messaging

I'm building a service that you can implant on your site with a single line of JavaScript code - think like a Facebook [like button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button).

So I'm adding code to `random.com`, and that code is loaded from `mysite.com/js.js`.

If the user is not logged in, I don't want to have them log in through an iframe for security - I open a window where they can log in. When they successfully log in, I need the parent window to fetch a new [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token. So I need to be able to tell the parent window to do so.

I have this working within iframes for other actions, but when I try from a window with this code:

```
window.parent.postMessage('message', '*');
```

Nothing happens. If I change the `*` to `random.com`, I get this error:

> Unable to post message to http://random.com. Recipient has origin https://mysite.com

I'm thinking that has to be, because the script which adds the listener:

```
$(window).bind('message', myfunction);
```

It is actually in the script on mysite.com.

But what's strange is that when an iframe calls the exact same script it works perfectly! And also the iframe calls it with the targetOrigin set to `random.com` (which causes the security error above).

Answer (score 7):

`window.parent` only works with iframes and `window.opener` works with separate windows.

On top of that, since I was trying to send a message to the parent window, but the new window was opened by the iframe IN that window.

So `window.opener` reached the iframe - then I had to actually send the message to its parent:

```
window.opener.parent.postMessage(etc, etc);
```